# reledmac – font of "L" and "R" in linenumber of endnotes

Tags: reledmac

I have text in two parallel columns and when I create an endnote it prints page, line-number followed by either "L" or "R" for the left or right column, i.e. 302,637R would be page 302, line 637, right column. But how can I change the font of the R to a smaller font?

In the manual this seems to be the code:

> 238 XX Endnotes

> The \endprint here is nearly identical in its functioning to \normalfootfmt.

> The endnote file also contains \l@d@section commands, which supply the section  numbers from the main text; standard reledmac does nothing with this information, but it is there if you want to write custom macros to do something with it. Ar-
> guments are:

> • #1 Line numbers and font selection. • #2 Lemma.
>
> • #3 Note content.
>
> • #4 Series.
>
> • #5 Optional argument of \Xendnote. • #6Side(LorR).
>
> • #7 Label for cross-referencing.

In my real world example this is the endnote to print:

```
\def
\sw@list@inedtext
{}%
\parse@annot
||%
\Aend{302|637|0|302|637|0|TU/garamond(0)/m/n}{\no@expands
\textnormal
{\emph
{Why}}}{\textnormal
{Some note}}{A}{}{R}{edtxt@631}%
```

One can spot the {R} that I try to access. How can I do this?

Comment: It is very hard to replicate your issue and look for a solution from your very few, very abstract hints. Please provide a MWE that we can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @marquinho is right, I should’ve created an MWE. When I boiled down the code i saw the switch I had implemented. So the following code produces the wrong output [image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\NewCommandCopy{\printnpnumSave}{\printnpnum}
\renewcommand*{\printnpnum}[1]{{\noindent}\tiny}
\Xendsep{}
\Xendafterpagenumber[A]{, }
\Xendnotenumfont[A]{\tiny}

\Xendnotenumfont{\huge{}}


\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
some text to the left
\pend
\pstart
this is in the 
\edtext{left column}{\Aendnote{note}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\end{pairs}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
some text to the right
\pend
\pstart
this is
\edtext{in the right column}{\Aendnote{note}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}\Columns
\vspace{2em}
\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

but when one removes `\Xendnotenumfont{\huge{}}` everything is fine.